# Прокрастинація - проволока чи зволікання?

Tags: вибір-слова, відповідник

Цікавить відповідник до слова "[прокрастинація](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F)" (*психологічний термін, означає схильність особи відкладати на потім, на завтра, на майбутнє неприємні рішення та справи*).

На [Словотворі](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/prokrastynatsiia) першим із варіантів є слово "проволока", яке ми знаходимо і в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/provoloka) із значенням:

> Затримка, зволікання при виконанні чого-небудь.

Однак, збоку бачимо позначку **розм.**, тому я не впевнений, що його можна буде вживати у всіх видах текстів. На тому ж Словотворі бачимо "зволікання", яке чомусь не є настільки популярним як перший варіант, однак мені здається, що саме воно підійде краще, адже у слова "[зволікати](http://sum.in.ua/s/zvolikaty)" є таке значення:

> Відкладати, затримувати що-небудь, затягувати виконання, здійснення
>   чогось на довший строк.

Як бачимо, саме "зволікання" найкраще передає значення слова "прокрастинація". Однак, на Словотворі все ж зазначено найкращим відповідником "проволока", тому як бути і яке ж з цих слів використовувати? Чи їх можна вважати синонімами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Якщо глянути в англомовну [Вікіпедію](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procrastination), то знайдемо таке пояснення самого терміна:

> **Procrastination** - from Latin's "procrastinare", that translates as: the prefix pro-, 'forward', with -crastinus, 'till next day' from "cras", 'tomorrow'.

Якщо ж перекласти, то бачимо, що **"procrastinare"** складається з двох частин: ***префікс [pro-] - вперед + суфікс [-crastinus] - до наступного дня.***

В [англійсько-українському словнику](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/procrastination) знайшла варіант:

> **зволікання**.

Отже, як на мене, *найкращі відповідники у літературній мові* - це слова "**відкладання**" та "**зволікання**", що виступають синонімами.

Щодо використання слова "*проволока*", то, як пише наведений Вами СУМ-11, його вживаємо *ЛИШЕ у розмовній мові*, що дещо обмежує його побутування.